# Issues with negative z-index in IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, z-index

I am using two pseudo elements to create a banner effect on a div, like so:

```
div { position: relative; width: 200px; background-color: #999; }
div:before, div:after { content: ""; width: 10px; height: 0; display: block; position: absolute; z-index: -1; top: 10px; border-top: 10px solid #666; border-bottom: 10px solid #666; }
div:before { right: -20px; border-right: 10px solid transparent; border-left: 10px solid #333; }
div:after { left: -20px; border-left: 10px solid transparent; border-right: 10px solid #333; }
```

It works fine in FF, Chrome, Safari & IE9, but no luck with IE8. The two elements with z-index of -1 show above parent. Is there any way to get this to work?

Comment: Please refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5540177/ie8-z-index-on-before-and-after-css-selectors/5543472#5543472) answer @smdrager really helped out by explaining how it works and showed an excellent example

Comment: I have the same problem. Not found a workaround yet.

Answer (score 2):

You should try setting a `z-index` of 1 to `div`.

Comment: Tried that. Still broken in IE8, and now also broken in every other browser. Any other ideas?