# Negative :before z-index on absolutely positioned element not working in IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, css-position, z-index, pseudo-element

I've searched about this problem and know that IE8 has quirks rendering elements with pseudo tags but couldn't find solution for my problem. I'm trying to position absolutely an element and add to it a pseudo :before element which must be *beneath* its parent.

Using:

```css
.container:before {
    z-index: -1;
}
```

do the trick with Firefox and Chrome but not on IE; Here's the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/WaTnn/

How can I position the yellow element beneath the red in IE8 and still have it's parent be absolutely positioned?

Comment: Is this helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8828767/z-index-ie8-bug-on-generated-content-with-after?rq=1

Comment: It gave me and idea of how to do it. I've added the solution at the bottom.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found a working solution:

1. Add a relatively positioned div inside the container
2. Set its `z-index: -1`
3. Add the `:before` element to the div not to the container.

Here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/WaTnn/3/

If someone has a better solution, I'd be happy to see it.

Answer (score 1):

As it says here: [link](http://css-tricks.com/browser-support-pseudo-elements/)

> ```
> IE8 Partial Support
> z-index not respected, must use a doctype, must declare a :hover state if you use :hover:after/:hover:before
> ```