# IE8 before element with absolute child

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, z-index

I got a div, a :before-element and inner elements. Everything works fine, except one inner element is positioned `absolute`.

Using z-index, it's possible to position the absolute element behind the :before-element. This does not work in IE8, as posted in [IE8 z-index on before and after css selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5540177/ie8-z-index-on-before-and-after-css-selectors). As mentioned in that post one could use `position: relative` to fix the problem. But as my element is already positioned `absolute`, there is no way I could do that. So what can I do to fix this?

I create a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2Zcr9/4/ to show my problem (for IE8, go to http://jsfiddle.net/2Zcr9/4/embedded/result/, as jsfiddle no longer supports IE8).

---

**Edit:** Changed the links, as Paul_D pointed out that my fiddle was wrong + picture
[image]
See the difference. Normal browsers got the yellow absolute element behind the `:before-element` if z-index is lower, but IE8 refuses to do that.

Comment: You JSfiddle has no `:before` pseudo-element although it does have a `:after`. I'm still confused about what you are trying to do.

Comment: woops, my mistake. It should have been a `:before`.

Comment: Fair enough, I don't thin kit matters but I can't see what the issue is. Do you have an image of how it looks in IE8 as I can't see any issue in IE8 "mode" in IE11. I'm still having trouble working out what it is you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. When given the yellow element a negative z-index, it's parent a positive z-index and the `:before-element` a higher z-index, the `:before-element` stacks as highest, even in IE8. See also: http://jsfiddle.net/2Zcr9/23/.

Notices the difference between .icon and p. P still stackes above the `:before-element` in IE9, as it has not a negative z-index.

---

To be more global: after much trying and error I came to understand that the shadow dom is always stacked lower than the children in IE8.

An example:

```
<div id="parent">
     :before
     <div id="child1"></div>
     <div id="child2"></div>
     :after
</div>
```

the `:before` and `:after` elements are stacked lower than resp. #child1 and #child2. One could fix that by applying following CSS:

```
#parent { position: relative; z-index: 2 }
#parent:before { position: absolute; z-index: 3; ... }
#parent > * { position: relative; z-index: -1 }
```